# I want to compare sql servers date time function value and selected columns value

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, date, time

Here is my code `2016-09-08 05:57:03.513`, this is the date-time format I want to compare.

I think something wrong in converting.

I want to compare the selected row with sql column where I have used a `getdate` function which has the date time in above type

```
try {
    String buy_qty=qtycus.getText();
    Integer bq= Integer.parseInt(buy_qty);
    Integer aa = sell_outside_cus.getSelectedRow();
    String rr=sid_sell.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String dat = sell_outside_cus.getValueAt(aa,2).toString();
    System.out.println(dat);
    Date result;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm ");
    try {
        result = formatter.parse (dat);
        System.out.println(result);

        String namesup = sell_outside_cus.getValueAt(aa,4).toString();
        Integer s_avilable=Integer.parseInt(namesup);
        Integer rest= s_avilable-bq;
        System.out.println(rest);
        try {
            String sql=("UPDATE supreg SET available_stock=('"+rest+"') where ((SupplementId='"+rr+"')AND(supadd_date='"+result+"'))");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs= pst.executeQuery();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);          
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String sql = ("UPDATE supreg SET available_stock=? where ((SupplementId=?)AND(supadd_date=to_date(?, yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss))");
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, rest);
pst.setString(2, dat);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

And don't write like this:

```
String sql=("UPDATE supreg SET available_stock=('"+rest+"') where ((SupplementId='"+rr+"')AND(supadd_date='"+result+"'))");
```

Because this code has been making mistake SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

> I have used a getdate function which has the date time in above type

**This is not true!!** `GETDATE()` returns a typesafe `DATETIME`. What you see is a string representation which is prepared for the human reader. Which **format** is used depends on culture settings. You should never compare date/time values on string level...

#### Your command:

In this line your are creating your command by concatenating all your values in the correct places, just as if you'd write this in SSMS or in a SQL console.

```
String sql=("UPDATE supreg SET available_stock=('"+rest+"') where ((SupplementId='"+rr+"')AND(supadd_date='"+result+"'))");
```

This is a bad approach because

- you have to deal with the correct string representation of a value yourself, which can be quite a mess. Date-Time-Values are especially prone to problems due to cultural differences!
- this is open for sql injection (high security risk)

### Good approach

Use paramters instead of the concatenation. This keeps it type safe and secure.

### Bad approach

If you have to stick to this, you must ensure valid string literals

DateTime might be put in these Formats (all examples for 2016.12.31 23:59:59)

- unseparated (date only): "20161231"
- ISO 8601: "2016-12-31T23:59:59"
- ODBC (date only): "{d'2016-12-31'}"
- ODBC (date and time): "{ts'2016-12-31 23:59:59'}"
- ODBC (time only): "{t'23:59:59'}"

And to avoid implicit castings you should write something like

```
AND(supadd_date=CONVERT(DATETIME,'"+result+"',key))
```

While `key` is the proper value for your chosen format [from here, e.g. 126 for ISO8601](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Any other format might lead to exceptions or misinterpretations (e.g. 2016-09-08 might be a date in September or in August. This is depending on the system's culture).